# Unity Error When Trying To Detect Collided Game Object To Apply Damage (Unity3d - C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I am attempting to detect the tag of the enemy collided with, and if its tag is Enemy, then access it's current health within its script (EnemyAI) and deduct the attack damage amount.

The code seems correct however i'm getting this error in Unity; **"The name 'collision' does not exist in the current context".**

I have multiple enemies and i've tagged all with Enemy. The idea being that if the player attacks one of them, it will detect that it's an enemy due to its tag and then access its script to apply the damage.

The code I currently have is:

```
                //Detect enemies in range of attack
                Collider[] hitEnemies = Physics.OverlapSphere(attackPoint.position, attackRange, enemyLayers);

                //Hurt enemy
                if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
                {
                    //Damage them
                    collision.gameObject.GetComponent<EnemyAI>().currentHealth -= attackDamage;
                }
```

I also tried using `public void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)`, adding the code to it and then calling it but I need to pass a value into it. I tried passing in Collider and I get an error saying its a type. I tried collider instead and I get the same error **"The name 'collision' does not exist in the current context".**

I'm stuck, i'd appreciate the help a lot.

I've reverted back to calling `OnCollisionEnter(collision);`  and then it goes to:

```
        public void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
        {
            if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
            {
                //Damage them
                collision.gameObject.GetComponent<EnemyAI>().currentHealth -= attackDamage;
            }
        }
```

Same error message: **The name 'collision' does not exist in the current context".**

Comment: Hi, please include the complete method that you are using

Comment: Which function is it? 
OnCollisionEnter or OnTriggerEnter?

Comment: @Mario updated that in my question for you.

Comment: @HasnainShaukat I'm using OnCollisionEnter.

Comment: Is UnityEngine library added?

Comment: @HasnainShaukat It is yes ```using UnityEngine;```

Comment: @HasnainShaukat I realised I hadn't declared collision so I added ```public Collision collision;```. The error is now gone, however when I try to attack with the player I get a new error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." because it's encountering a null value at runtime.

Comment: Then try regenerating project files in preferences. 
and 
restart Unity.
You could try "reimport all" as the last resort.

Comment: No you don't need to declare it, it's function parameter.

Comment: @HasnainShaukat Ok, i'll remove that. I didn't think I did but after it removed the error it had me questioning my original thought.

Comment: @HasnainShaukat I'll try regenerating project files as you suggested. Can't seem to find it in preferences but i'll work it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've mixed OnCollision syntax into your code. Currently there is no **collision** created/set anywhere in your code (context). There are only **colliders** that are returned by the overlapsphere. Hence why you get the error. You need to handle them a bit differently.

```csharp
//Detect enemies in range of attack
Collider[] hitEnemies = Physics.OverlapSphere(attackPoint.position, attackRange, enemyLayers);

foreach(Collider enemyCol in hitEnemies){
  //Hurt enemy
  if (enemyCol.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
  {
    //Damage them
    enemyCol.gameObject.GetComponent<EnemyAI>().currentHealth -= attackDamage;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes more sense. I have made changes and the error is resolved. Only thing now is that the damage isn't deducted from the players health. I added a debug log after the foreach line to check if the collision is being detected, but its not returning anything so it's not detecting the collision.

Comment: Player and enemy do have their relevant tags. Both have rigid body components. Do they require box/capsule colliders for this to work?

Comment: The overlapsphere is detecting the collision however. So that would indicate a problem with the tags?

Comment: Thanks for your patience with me. This is resolved now, I just had to add a capsule collider to the enemy in addition to using the code you provided.

Comment: @WolfPG no real patience I was just going about my day while you figured it out :)
The current code is enemy specific (Tag and Component), so it wouldn't damage the player. You might want to make a health script that both the enemy and player share, sot that you can reuse it.